# Redshift CDC or delta load

Tags: amazon-redshift

Any one knows best way for loading delta or CDC with using any tools

I got big table with billions of records and want to update or insert like Merge in Sql server or Oracle but in Amazon Redshift S3

Also we have loads of columns as can't compare all columns as well

e.g

TableA
Col1 Col2 Col3 ...

It has say already records
SO when inserting new records need to check that particular record is already existing if so no insert if not insert and if changed update record like that
I do have key id and date columns but as its got 200+ columns not easy to check all columns and taking much time

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two very different databases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Redshift database